# vSphere - unable to increase disk size of windows guest disk

Tags: vmware-vsphere, vmware-esx

ESX 5.5, vcenter 5.5, vsphere 5.5

Reading vmware kb's, it sounds like I should be able to come in here and increase disk size...

But can't....

Shut down guest.

Still can't.

There are no snapshots (according to snapshot manager for this VM).

I need to make the C: of this Win10 VM substantially bigger.

How?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if all the snapshots have been removed.  I don't think you can resize the disk if there are snapshots.

Comment: Nay, there are no snapshots

Comment: Did you check the Data store as there can be hidden Snaps.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a vsphere artifact of some kind.

When I first went to do this, and reported issue above, the VM was running, and this GUI element is locked, by design. Later, after shutting off the VM, the edit was still locked.

Today, the VM had been shut down for some time, and I went to edit the VM, and now the setting IS editable.